# Disable a button on page load with a specific ID

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have multiples buttons on my asp.net page, I need to disable certain button(s) on page load.
Which button will be disabled is determined by my database, which I successfully retrieved.

For example, I have retrieved the ID "B01", and in my page there's a button's ID named "B01"
I have to disable this button on page load, how do I do it?

Comment: Can you posted your button code?

Answer (score 1):

Just do - `if(!IsPostBack){id.Enabled = false;}` on page load and make sure button must be like  `<asp:Button ID="btn_dn" runat="server" >Button</asp:Button>` button need `runat="server"`

As you are using simple button so it will not take any c# command so you have to use asp button or javascript to disable button

for simple button `<input type="button" disabled="disabled" value="B01" />` Or 

`<button id="B01" runat="server" disabled="disabled">B01</button>`

Comment: there's no Enabled after id.

Comment: it means your control is not coming.. on load.. get your button control before that id.enabled line. other wise it will show Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: i have no idea what button control button is, but i have googled it, and still end up with nothing. can you help me further?

Comment: as u say u r creating dynamic button.. ok?

Comment: i think u r confused.. just tell me yr procedure of creating buttons and other controls.. and what exactly result u want?

Comment: i have buttons in my asp page, with ID. and i need to disable certain buttons with an id coming out of my database, which i successfully did, when my database have the id "B01", i need to disable the button "B01" on page load, now i have B01, but i dont know how do i disable this specific button using c#.

Comment: ok buddy.. u r using simple button then asp so u have to use asp button or javascript for this.,,  See my updated answer.. you will get your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in `Page_Load` event

```
string id="B01";
(FindControl(id) as Button).Enabled = false;
```

Comment: this is not working, Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Sorry, typing mistake. Now check my answer

Comment: still the same, what did you type wrongly by the way?

Comment: I thought it was BO1, instead of B01

Comment: Is it a server control?

Comment: <button id="B01" runat="server"><img src="../Images/seat.jpg" /><br />
        B01</button>

Answer (score 0):

There are challenges with FindControl and "nested" controls. I believe you need a recursive find control function have a look at the tutorial.

```
public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control Root, string Id)
{



  if (Root.ID == Id)
        return Root;


foreach (Control Ctl in Root.Controls)
{
    Control FoundCtl = FindControlRecursive(Ctl, Id);
    if (FoundCtl != null)
        return FoundCtl;
}

return null;
}
```

then call it using

```
var x = FindControlRecursive(this.Master,"ButtonName") as Button;      
x.Visible = false or x.Enabled = false
```

[Tutorial Link is here....](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2006/Apr/09/ASPNET-20-MasterPages-and-FindControl)

Answer (score 0):

in page load:

```
string id = "A01";

var q = from R in db.Reservations
                    where R.Flight_NO == id
                    select R.Seat;


        foreach (var item in q)
        {
            Button b = (Button)this.Master.FindControl("main").FindControl(item);
            if (b!=null)
            {
                b.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
```

this does automatically disable button with that specific ID on page load